# Jquery - Get Data attribute text value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Getting Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: data-key['lifetimeStays']

want to get value from data-key="lifetimeStays" and data-key="lifetimeNights"

**HTML:**

```
<div data-cookies="profile-cred" data-key="lifetimeStays" class="value cookies-value">1110</div>

<div data-cookies="profile-cred" data-key="lifetimeNights" class="value cookies-value">9000</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$("data-key['lifetimeStays']").text();
$("data-key['lifetimeNights']").text();
```

Comment: You are using wrong [attribute selector syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code `$("data-key['lifetimeStays']")` means you select element `data-key` having attribute `lifetimeStays`, namely this element `<data-key lifetimeStays/>`.

Try this to select attribute which has specific value

```
$('[data-key=lifetimeStays]').text()
```

Answer (score 1):

use `$("[data-key='lifetimeStays']").text();`. `data-key` is an `attribute` https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/.

```js
console.log($("[data-key='lifetimeStays']").text());
console.log($("[data-key='lifetimeNights']").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-cookies="profile-cred" data-key="lifetimeStays" class="value cookies-value">1110</div>

<div data-cookies="profile-cred" data-key="lifetimeNights" class="value cookies-value">9000</div>
```